# Rails Unit Test Mystery: Method Runs, Value is Changed, Assertion Fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, mongomapper, testunit

I have a unit test that checks that a method does the following:

1. Finds all instances of a model with a certain value,
2. changes them to another value,
3. saves the models to the database.

The method appears to be doing what it is supposed to do, but the test database appears to be reverting to the original value.

```
class PostTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  test "publish queued posts" do
    post = Post.new({:published => 'queue'})
    post.save
    Post.handle_queue
    assert(post.published == 'published', "post should be published. actual value: #{post.published}")
  end
end
```

---

```
test_publish_queued_posts(PostTest) ../test/unit/post_test.rb:13]:
post should be published. actual value: queue
```

Stepping through the code, it is clear that `post`'s 'published' attribute is set to `published`, but some time between that point and the assertion, the value is changed back to `queue`.

This is terrible confusing. Do you have any idea what is happening here? I'm using mongo_mapper for persistence if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think reloading your model before assertion should do it.

```
post.reload
assert(post.published == 'published', "post should be published. actual value: #{post.published}")
```

Comment: Hey, that did it exactly! I've never used #reload (or had to use it) - I just assumed it would work.

Comment: This makes good sense now. `handle_queue` doesn't update the local variable `post` with the changes that have been made in the database.